# How can I solve "Got minus one from a read call" in oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I run the sql developer and set the all data,click the connect but i get this error:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
```

I am beginner in Oracle. How can I solve that error?

I use 64-bit Windows7 and oracle 12c.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

In my case the error is connected to a problem about the client's (SQL Developer) ojdbc8 driver and the Oracle 19.3 docker container. The solution for me was to set a system property on the client -- you can do it within the JDBC connection string):

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@tcp://host:port/service?oracle.net.disableOob=true
```

[This is the thread](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1663) that lead me to the answer.

The cause of the error is described here:

https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=357910144923387

You can also solve this problem by dissabling OOB on server side in the sqlnet.ora:

DISABLE_OOB=ON

Another workaround is to use the ojdbc7 driver.

Hope this helps some of us.

Comment: Where do I change the JDBC connection string?  I've never used that before?

Comment: FYI... I applied this fix to my testcontainer setup. Locally nothing bad happened, 
Jenkins however failed with this elusive "IO Error: Got minus one from a read call".
This actually worked, however... I have no idea why and, to me, it makes 0 sense...

Comment: @dougd_in_nc Sorry for the late answer, just read it. In the connection properties of your db connection in sqldeveloper u can switch the connection type to "custom jdbc" and enter the connection string in there

Comment: @YoeriVanNieuwerburg have you tried switching jenkins to ojdbc7 driver as workaround?

Comment: @starguy  I saw in the Advanced tab of the Database Connections dialog that I could set properties so I just set the property oracle.net.disableOob to true and it worked.

Comment: @starguy nope, but tbh, I'm not sure if that should be done... after all, it's maven/gradle/... which should handle the dependencies imho.
And... the Jenkins I'm dealing with is one which has some limitations towards devs... unfortunately ;)
However, as I said, the fix with "disableOob=true" works well. :D

Comment: Thank you! Setting DISABLE_OOB=ON in sqlnet.ora and restarting my docker container worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

From your inputs in the dialog, you are using port 5500. That port is what is used for EM Express. It answers to HTTPs traffic only. So in this case the -1 error message means the protocol negotiation failed. SQLDEV is trying to talk SQL*NET to something listening for HTTPs.

The port you are looking for is 1521 if it wasn't altered. If it was check the $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora for the proper port number.

Answer (score 2):

You need set "**tcp.validnode_checking** = no" or comment this parameter in sqlnet.ora file then **restart** *listener* on db server and test again.

Try it.

Comment: how to find the proper sqlnet.ora file? I have only four inside docker/overlay2

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue but following steps worked for me, it seems Gaurav also has shared it already:

```
1.Go to the folder where you have installed the database (Like: F:\app)
2.Here you will be able to see many folders, go to product\11.2.0("your databse version")\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
3.find listener.ora file and open as text file
4.Check for the port number in that file
5.Now provide that port number while doing connection in sql developer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have enabled ACL on the listener.

You can follow these steps to avoid the error:

```
1. Go to directory $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
2. Modify sqlnet.ora file with following parameter: 
tcp.validnode_checking = no

3. If you don't want to disable this, you can put the machine names as follows:
tcp.invited_nodes=(machine1, machine2)

3. Bounce the listener.
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the DB is up and running and you can connect locally AS SYSDBA to the database using Oracle binaries owner (usually oracle:oinstall Unix / Linux user). If it does not work, probably you encounter a different problem.
Check privileges of an Oracle file on Unix / Linux host where database is running:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
ls -ltr oracle
-rwxr-xr-x    1 oracle   oinstall       136803483 Mar 16 20:32 oracle
```

Change permissions as below:

```
chmod 6751 oracle
ls -ltr oracle
-rwsr-s--x    1 oracle   oinstall       136803483 Mar 16 20:32 oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was given wrong host and port. I typed "tnsping yourServiceName" in command line in window 10. It returns a different host and port, then I used the correct one in sql developer and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened when I was using Docker with Oracle 19C.
The workaround is to find the listener.ora file, change 'PORT' and restart the container, ORACLE DB, listener.

It is presumed to be an error that occurred when the host tried to access TCP because it was already LISENT (HOST) by another process.
(When accessing Docker, consider that in most cases, you are accessing localhost.)

[image]

I changed the port to 1523, and all the problems were solved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do what the [link](http://itconquer.com/news/45/63/Cloud-Control-12C-Database-Discovery-Test-Connection-fails-with-IO-Error-Got-minus-one-from-a-read-call) , or check listener directory permission, or use command /dbhome/bin/relink all

Answer (score -1):

Try 
Connection name: HR_ORCL 
Username: HR ,
Password: hr ,
Connection type : local, 
Role: SYSDBA
Click on connect.
It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, It is not database specific issue. it is related to port value generated by database during your installation. To overcome on this issue, please follow below.

1. Go to the folder where you have installed the database (Like: F:\app)
2. Here you will be able to see many folders, go to product\11.2.0("your databse version")\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN
3. find listener.ora file and open as text file
4. Check for the port number in that file
5. Now provide that port number while doing connection in sql developer.

Hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: I have my ports set up for a tunnel. It's not the real database server port

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers out there for this problem point to using the wrong PORT number in your connection options, or similar. In my case, after a couple hours of searching, the reason showed to be something else.

Mind which user you are using when starting Oracle listener. You should do it with the ***oracle*** user, not as ***root***. Otherwise you end up with listener files being created as e.g. user *deamon* group *root* instead of user *oracle* group *dba*. This in turn leads to:

```
TNS-12555: TNS:permission denied
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00525: Insufficient privilege for operation
   Linux Error: 1: Operation not permitted
```

To check whether this is the case, go to

```
/var/tmp/.oracle
```

and list all files (ls -la). If you find out some of the s#* files being created by a root-group user, stop the listener (lsnrctl stop), delete the above files as root and restart the listener as *oracle* user.

Unfortunately sqldeveloper doesn't show the full stack-trace when reading "Got minus one from a read call". I could find the problem thanks to switching to SQL-Squirrel.

Comment: I have my ports set up for a tunnel.  It's not the real database server port